# How to achieve MS word tab function in html/ css?

Tags: html, css

Now I am writing a html file, which just want to duplicate the MS Word file outlook for further programming. However, how to achieve the following image?[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5rnf.png)

At this stage, I can't make the two colons stand into same position, since I just use underscore.
Thank you for your help.

---

Now I can only achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5xEc.png).
By this code:

```css
.box{float:left; margin-right:10px;}
input{border:0;border-bottom:1px solid #000;  background: transparent;
  outline: none;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable style="display:inline-block; min-width:50px;">Applicant’s signature</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable style="display:inline-block; min-width:50px;">Date</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable style="display:inline-block; min-width:50px;">Applicant’s name</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll need to post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box{float:left; margin-right:10px;}
lable{display:inline-block; min-width:50px;}
input{border:0;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable>Date</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable>Name</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable>Name</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>
  <div class="box">
      <lable>Name</lable>
<span>:</span>
    <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bhai naye logon ko bi practice ka mauka dona...ham aise hi answers  dethe chale jayengetho thik nahi hoga StackOverflow ka maqsad ye nahi hai  koibi aise bina kuch code show kare...hame unhe answers kaise denge. This very important.

Comment: next time i'll do better

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I face some problem and I updated it for my question.